# What is hostname for remote database

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

I have two databases: one local, one remote. While I can connect to the local database, I am having trouble making the remote connection. I've added my IP address under "CPanel" => "Remote MySQL".

What would be the hostname parameter for my call to `mysqli_connect`?

Please correct me if I'm wrong in creating a remote database connection.

Comment: Depending on how your local computer and network are configured your remote server may be entirely unable to access the database. The remote MySQL feature on cPanel is for external sources to connect to databases **on** the server, not for scripts on the server to connect to external sources.

Answer (score 1):

try this code for evalute error

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect(hostname, userame, passwrd, dbname);

    if (!$link) {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: can you please tell me what will be the hostname for remote database connection?
is it the ip address that i have mention in remote mysql settings of cpanel?

Comment: Normally the ip address is allowed

Comment: issue is with the firewall.. i have resolved it.. thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

While this is old and op no longer needs an answer, this may help others:

```
<?php
    define("HOSTNAME", "example.com"); // your domain name in place of localhost
    define("DBUSER", "exampleuser");
    define("DBNAME", "exampledb");
    define("DBPASS", "mysecretpassword");
$conn = mysqli_connect( HOSTNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME );
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to find your servers IP Address by ping

```
ping mydomain.com
```

you will get your server ip from there. Ip address is your servers hostname also you use your domain name as hostname. Next put it to your remote mysqli 
**Remote connection.**

```
$db_host = 'your server ip address';
$devdb   = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name, $db_port);
```

**Localhost  connection.**

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$devdb   = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name, $db_port);
```

More info can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php